# Partial power out when AC is on

Tags: hvac, electrical-panel, power-supply

Anytime our AC is on we lose power in a few rooms mostly the kitchen. It can be on a few days before it goes out. I’ve had 2 electricians come they both said electric panel looks great , we did replace 3 breakers that were a little loose but they say if it happens again replace the electric panel, I don’t think that’s the issue. Had the utility company come today to make sure it wasn’t anything on their end and they tested everything on the house and said it was good so they wouldn’t check out at the pole. Has anyone else had this problem? I’m spending money for electricians to come look and they aren’t even sure they just want to replace things and see if that works.

Comment: Call your utility and tell them you have a partial power outage they will check the service for free and usually right away since this can cause fires. What is the brand of your main panel?

Comment: I did they came today. They looked at the meter and said everything was good so they wouldn’t check at the pole. It’s cutler hammer

Comment: If everything is good at the meter from the utilities guys and everything is good at the panel you may have to call when it is happening. Is your AC on a sub panel that part of the home may also be on? You will need to map out everything that is out, if boots on the ground can’t figure it out we have no chance without more information. What’s turned on what’s not working a complete map when it happens.

Comment: Can you post photos of your electrical panel please?

Comment: I am not an electrical engineer, but I sense you are drawing more power than the supply. You need someone to do a calculation based on your equipment and usage, then work on the electrical panel (you may need to upsize it).

Comment: Sounds like a loose hot leg connection someplace. Could be at the main breaker, the meter base, the connection at the mast head (if overhead service) or the transformer.  If you are comfortable with doing this, when it happens, pull the cover off your main panel and use a digital multi meter to take readings across both hots (should be about 240v) and each hot to neutral (should be about 120v). Be careful, this is the real deal here and if not comfortable, get an electrician to do the measurements when it's happening.   ...more to follow, not an answer bc I dk enough yet!

Comment: ....continuing... If not 120v to neutral from both hots, you have an open neutral (not likely, but if so, very dangerous) .how long does it take when power in the affected outlets is restored after the A/C turns off?   Does the A/C continue to run when the other outlets are affected? More information about the A/C would be helpful too:  Is it a whole house A/C system? What voltage?  Or is it something like a portable, or window A/C unit? Makes and models help us a lot to give you a quality answer

Comment: Thank you I will have all this checked. I did forget to mention the breakers don’t trip when I lose power. The a/c is for the whole house. I’m sorry I don’t know much,just looking for suggestions. I’m young & know nothing about electric. I had very expensive estimates for things to be fixed but they weren’t 100% sure that was the problem so I was conflicted. When this happens I had flipped all the breakers off then back on that usually gets everything back on but I’ve been keeping the ac off because that’s when it happens.

Comment: I had the ac on for 2 days after replacing a few breakers like the electrician suggested. This morning i turned on the kitchen light they were very dim so i turned the ac off from thermostat and lost power. I tried to get both electricians out today while it happened but they weren’t available. I’ve kept the ac off today and had the utility people come check because i seen that suggested on another thread here.

Comment: I had a main breaker that was acting to cut power to half the house. It would heat up and spread open on one leg interrupting power for half the feed.   Cool down and everything would seem normal.  This was a 100 amp main in outside panel for mobile home.   Replaced it and noticed the casing was cracked around the contacts.  Maybe a lightening strike caused it.   No problems since replacing it.